# Create column indicating historical existence of specific value based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have `df` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'B': [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True]
})
```

`df` is already sorted by `A` (obviously) and time (descending). So for each group defined by `A`, the vlues in `B` are time sorted descendingly. What I want to do is to add a columns `C` which, for each group, is `True` if there is a `True` value in `B` in the past. The result would look like:

```
    A   B       C
0   a   False   True
1   a   True    False
2   a   False   False
3   a   False   False
4   b   True    True
5   b   False   True
6   b   False   True
7   b   True    False
```

I suspect I need to use `groupby()` and `idxmax()` somehow but haven't been able to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC here's one way:

```
rev_cs = df[::-1].groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0.).gt(0))
df['C'] = rev_cs[::-1]
```

---

```
print(df)

  A      B      C
0  a  False   True
1  a   True  False
2  a  False  False
3  a  False  False
4  b   True   True
5  b  False   True
6  b  False   True
7  b   True  False
```

Answer (score 4):

`idxmax` is the way with `transform`

```
df['New']=df.index<df.iloc[::-1].groupby('A').B.transform('idxmax').sort_index()
df
   A      B    New
0  a  False   True
1  a   True  False
2  a  False  False
3  a  False  False
4  b   True   True
5  b  False   True
6  b  False   True
7  b   True  False
```

If all False

```
s1=df.index<df.iloc[::-1].groupby('A').B.transform('idxmax').sort_index()
s2=df.groupby('A').B.transform('any')
df['New']=s1&s2
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! If you don't mind clarifying a few things for a noob like me: (1) Is `df.iloc[::-1]` just for making the order ascending? Can it be skipped if the time order is ascending by default? (2) How can I know that `idxmax` can be used inside the `transform`? Is that something that can be read from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)?

Comment: @CHRD yes that is change the ascending , most of the agg function in pandas can be used in transform

Comment: @YOBEN_S I realized that this solution fails if there are groups where all `B`-values are `False`. In that case this behaves as if the first value for each group is `True` due to the behavior of `idxmax`. Any thoughts?

Comment: The solution by @yatu handles this well but I'm still curious: can you adapt your solution to fit "all `False`"-cases as well? :)